# Tracing odd variant of call analysis failed

Tags: ida, disassembly, calling-conventions

Disclaimer before I get flogged: I'm playing with a commercial app, for which I have a license, for my own education because building toy C apps has run out of challenge (and I know whats inside).

That said, I opened up a .so, the contents of which I know nothing about, and got the dreaded `33AB0: call analysis failed`. Looking at that line, it's a `call` to a function, which is an `extern`. So I know even less about it than the library im looking at. Weirdly that same `call` happens multiple times before the line causing the error, and it seems IDA is ok with those invokes. It looks like this:

```
.text:00033A1C                 mov     dword ptr [esp+18h], 0
.text:00033A24                 mov     dword ptr [esp+14h], 0
.text:00033A2C                 mov     [esp+10h], eax
.text:00033A30                 mov     dword ptr [esp+0Ch], (offset aFmt+1) ; "fmt"
.text:00033A38                 mov     dword ptr [esp+8], 1
.text:00033A40                 mov     dword ptr [esp+4], offset unk_51988
.text:00033A48                 mov     dword ptr [esp], 3
.text:00033A4F                 call    log_dispatch
.text:00033A54                 jmp     loc_33786
.text:00033A54 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:00033A59                 align 10h
.text:00033A60
.text:00033A60 loc_33A60:                              ; CODE XREF: ff_init_entry+136↑j
.text:00033A60                 call    get_sw_date
.text:00033A65                 mov     dword ptr [esp+8], offset byte_52420
.text:00033A6D                 mov     [esp+4], eax
.text:00033A71                 mov     dword ptr [esp], offset aSoftwareVersio 
.text:00033A78                 call    lfmt
.text:00033A7D                 mov     dword ptr [esp+18h], 0
.text:00033A85                 mov     dword ptr [esp+14h], 0
.text:00033A8D                 mov     [esp+10h], eax
.text:00033A91                 mov     dword ptr [esp+0Ch], (offset aFmt+1) ; "fmt"
.text:00033A99                 mov     dword ptr [esp+8], 1
.text:00033AA1                 mov     dword ptr [esp+4], offset unk_519E8
.text:00033AA9                 mov     dword ptr [esp], 3
.text:00033AB0                 call    log_dispatch    <---- CALL ANALYSIS FAILED
.text:00033AB5                 jmp     loc_337BC
.text:00033ABA ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:00033ABA
.text:00033ABA loc_33ABA:                              ; CODE XREF: ff_init_entry+366↑j
.text:00033ABA                 mov     dword ptr [esp+4], 1F2h
.text:00033AC2                 mov     dword ptr [esp], offset aSoftwareDat 
.text:00033AC9                 call    lfmt
.text:00033ACE                 mov     dword ptr [esp+18h], 0
.text:00033AD6                 mov     dword ptr [esp+14h], 0
.text:00033ADE                 mov     [esp+10h], eax
.text:00033AE2                 mov     dword ptr [esp+0Ch], (offset aFmt+1) ; "fmt"
.text:00033AEA                 mov     dword ptr [esp+8], 1
.text:00033AF2                 mov     dword ptr [esp+4], offset unk_519A0
.text:00033AFA                 mov     dword ptr [esp], 3
.text:00033B01                 call    log_dispatch
.text:00033B06                 jmp     loc_339EC
```

Seems obvious it's doing some logging, and IDA believes `log_dispatch` is `int __cdecl log_dispatch(_DWORD, _DWORD, _DWORD, _DWORD, _DWORD, _DWORD, _DWORD);`, which also seems plausible to me.. How would I go about hunting this down? The answer is appreciated, but the path to find it myself is what I'm endeavoring to learn here..

UPDATED: In digging more, I found some oddness up in the PLT:

```
.plt:00013FA0 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.plt:00013FA0
.plt:00013FA0 ; Attributes: thunk
.plt:00013FA0
.plt:00013FA0 ; _DWORD __cdecl std::string::reserve(std::string *__hidden this, unsigned int)
.plt:00013FA0 __ZNSs7reserveEj proc near              ; CODE XREF: std::operator+<char>(char const*,std::string const&)+41↓p
.plt:00013FA0                 jmp     ds:off_4F018    ; PIC mode
.plt:00013FA0 __ZNSs7reserveEj endp
.plt:00013FA0
.plt:00013FA6 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.plt:00013FA6                 push    18h
.plt:00013FAB                 jmp     sub_13F60
.plt:00013FB0
.plt:00013FB0 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
```

The `push` and `jmp` outside the subroutine seems strange, though it seems to be the case with every entry in the PLT.. Not sure if this should be a hint to me, but messing with loading options on handling the PLT doesn't seem to change it..